# Mysql selecting unique values in date type varchar

Tags: mysql

I have a column where the dates are type varchar. For example:

```
15-10-2018
16-10-2018
19-10-2018
23-10-2018
29-10-2018
8-11-2018
9-11-2018
10-11-2018
12-11-2018
```

when I consult with the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT date FROM `test` WHERE date BETWEEN '15-10-2018' and '9-11-2018'.
```

I have the right result.

```
15-10-2018
16-10-2018
19-10-2018
23-10-2018
29-10-2018
8-11-2018
9-11-2018
```

but if the query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date FROM `test` WHERE date BETWEEN '15-10-2018' and '10-11-2018'.
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT date FROM `test` WHERE date BETWEEN '15-10-2018' and '12-11-2018'.
```

The answer I get is empty.

I think it's only validating the days in the sql.

I need to get the right dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the fact that the column is varchar, so it's comparing characters instead of a range of dates. I will recommend convert the column to date type and try again.

Alternative if you cannot change the type of the column you could cast it to date format like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `date` FROM `test` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '2018-10-15' AND '2018-11-10';
```

I tested with your data and it works. Of course this could put some extra effort on the database and will not use indexes.

Comment: The result is **Warning: #1292 Incorrect datetime value: '15-10-2018'** and **Warning: #1292 Incorrect datetime value: '16-10-2018'**

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. those date formats are not SQL valid. The valid format for dates is YYYY-MM-DD. You will need heavy adjust those format on the SQL to make it works. For sake of database performance, I will suggest fix the format before input them, make the column date type.

Comment: fixed the answer to use a correct function to fix the date format. Also fixed the range dates to be correct SQL compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the datatype to date and update your dates to be using date for a more reliable result. Once done you should be using the database format for the dates in your `WHERE` clause.

Try

`SELECT DISTINCT date FROM`test`WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-10-15' and '2018-11-10'`

Comment: when changing the data type all dates in the table are given values of **0000-00-00**